# read.delim() function for columns that start at different point in R

Tags: r, readr

So i'm trying to use the read.delim()function to look at a CSV (I know I can use read.csv(), but I need to do it this way). The csv file has columns that begin at different points, so how would I go about incorperating the code like that? The csv would look like this (example):

```
,,,Column_D, Column_E,
Column_A, Column_B, Column_C,,,
1,1,2,3,4,
.,.,.,.,.,
.,.,.,.,.,
```

Ive tried to do this:

```
    dataRAW <-  read_delim("./data/something.csv", delim = ",", col_types = cols(
          Column_A = col_integer(),
          Column_B = col_integer(),
          Column_C = col_integer(),
          Column_D = col_integer(),
          Column_E = col_integer()

        ), skip = 1)
```

What happens when R reads the file is that columns A B C have proper headings, but E and D don't. I would like all of them to have their proper headings. If I don't use the skip function, then columns D and E get proper headings, but then the other ones (ABC) don't.

Comment: How about skipping 2 lines and manually set colnames after that?

Comment: @Tung It worked, I realized I could just use the col_names(c()) and skip 2! I can't believe I overlooked that. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As proposed by @Tung you can skip the 2 first lines but then instead of manually setting the column names you can collect the two first lines from the data and combine them to set the column names.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- read_delim("~/Bureau/something.csv", delim = ",", skip = 2, col_names = FALSE) 
names1 <- read_delim("~/Bureau/something.csv", delim = ",", 
                     skip = 0, n_max = 1, col_names = FALSE) %>% t %>% as.vector
names2 <- read_delim("~/Bureau/something.csv", delim = ",", 
                     skip = 1, n_max = 1, col_names = FALSE) %>% t %>% as.vector
```

Remove the "NA" from the column names and then combine them with a simple paste.
Note that in your example the last column has no name and " Column_E" starts with a space character...

```r
names1[is.na(names1)] <- ""
names2[is.na(names2)] <- ""

colnames(d) <- paste0(names1, names2)

d
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   Column_A ` Column_B` ` Column_C` Column_D ` Column_E` ``   
#>   <chr>    <chr>       <chr>       <chr>    <chr>       <chr>
#> 1 1        1           2           3        4           <NA> 
#> 2 .        .           .           .        .           <NA> 
#> 3 .        .           .           .        .           <NA>
```

Created on 2018-03-10 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).